# Obj-c property getter infinite loop is finite

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter

I'm updating code that someone else wrote and I came across this infinite loop:

```
-(SelectionViewMode)getSelectionViewMode {
    return self.selectionViewMode; 
}
```

But in stepping through the debugger it only executes one time. Is this the compiler helping out?

selectionViewMode is declared in the .h file as:

```
@property (nonatomic) SelectionViewMode selectionViewMode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an infinite loop because Objective-C idiom is that accessors are named for the name of the property (i.e. `selectionViewMode` instead of `getSelectionViewMode`) without a prefix of any kind. Only setters are prefixed (with set). So your `getSelectionViewMode` method is just wrapping the actual getter.